# QueryDSL Collection query

Tags: querydsl

I want to create a QueryDSL query which checks whether an object A's list (listA, containing multiple objects of B) contains any objects B provided by a different list (providedList). If **ANY** objects B in the provided list also occur in listA I do not want to return object A.

What I have so far:

```
return query.from(objA).where(objA.listA.any().notIn(providedList)).list(objA);
```

However at the moment all the items in providedList have to not be in listA for this to work. Is there any way to make this work?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The query you're doing will filter all the rows inside the **objA** table. When you do apply the filter you're only showing all the rows that don't match any of item provided in that list.

To do not return anything when there is a match, you should check first if there is any row that match that provided list, for example with a count.

```
return query.from(objA).where(objA.listA.in(providedList)).list(objA.count());
```

If objA.count() is above 0 that method shouldn't return anything, if is 0 you can run your query normally without any filter.